# stop array conversion to objects for large arrays

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, object

I retrieving data from backend  to frontend from json, when I send small array It prints as array

```
[[["79.869594371948224,6.9351183796382223"],["79.869644126545694,6.9341375295332206"],.......
```

and when I send Large array it prints as an object

```
{"0":[["81.175402528806714,6.9255110868816949"],["81.1758192226863,6.9248754300773347"],........
```

I pass the same format result from the backend, and why this happens for large arrays? how to solve this?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: VM2034:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 18    because its object, for the small arrays works fine

Comment: @samrulz ss That would be useful information to share in you question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are wondering why json_encode() encodes your PHP array as a JSON object instead of a JSON array, you might want to double check your array keys because json_encode() assumes that you array is an object if your keys are not sequential.

```php
$foo = array('a','b','c');
print_r(json_encode($foo));
unset($foo[0]);
echo "\n";
print_r(json_encode($foo));
$foo = array_values($foo);
echo "\n";
print_r(json_encode($foo));

/** Output
["a","b","c"]
{"1":"b","2":"c"}
["b","c"]
*/
```